# Need hint to solve the following integral

Tags: real-analysis

We are fixed and need some hint to solve the problem
 $$\int\frac{(ax+b)^m}{(cx+d)^n}dx$$ where $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html

Comment: This integral Can be expressed by a Hypergeomtrical function

Comment: substitute $y=cx+d$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=cx+d$.

$$\int\frac{(ax+b)^m}{(cx+d)^n}dx=\frac{1}{c}\int\frac{\left(\frac{au}{c}+\frac{d(c-a)}{c}\right)^m}{u^n}du=\frac{1}{c^{m+1}}\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}a^{k}d^{m-k}(c-a)^{m-k}\int u^{k-n}du$$

Comment: Thank you, can we extend it to for $m,n\in \mathbb{Q}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. By the change of variable
$$
X=cx+d
$$ one is led to evaluate
$$
\int\frac{\left(X+\beta\right)^m}{X^n}
$$ which, by a binomial expansion, amounts to evaluate
$$
\int\frac{dX}{X^k}.
$$